# Form development

Tags: webform-civicrm

We are looking to create internship applications for our organization this summer. We don't want to use google forms and are wondering if there is something we can create using civicrm?

Wahaj Khan

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Do you already have a CiviCRM system?  If so what CMS are you using (Drupal, WordPress, Joomla)

Answer (score 3):

Wahaj Khan welcome to SE CiviCRM. If you are using

**Drupal**

You can use webform and webform CiviCRM module to create front end forms.

**Wordpress** 
You can use Caldera and Caldera CiviCRM plugins to create front end forms.

Above modules provide lots of option to control the actions from UI like making a field required based on a selection of a field, Online payments, sending emails etc

Cheers

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

[CiviGrant](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/grants/what-is-civigrant/) is designed to support applications for scholarships.

It supports the eligibility test part of an internship process. Possibly the value of the grant is zero which is the second role of CiviGrant and which you may not need. If CiviGrant is overkill for your purpose then stick to webform.